# Calling local webservice while browsing external website?

Tags: http, webservice-client

Hi all
It's my very first time asking question here. So, please bear with me. 
The scenario is like this:
I'll be using a web browser from a multifunction printer to access a website,say at 202.123.x.x. There will be a scan button on the page on that site. When I click on it, I want to call the scanning web service which is published on the machine like http://localhost:8000/...?wsdl. Is this scenario possible? FYI, the web service is using SOAP.
If it's possible, do I have to write on front end like javascript or backend jsp/java coding?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will generally have problems with Same-Origin-Policy that will prevent you from using the XMLHTTPRequest object. You may be able to do a cross-site form post, but that depends on whether you can call the service in a fire-and-forget manner.

Comment: Hi Eric, can you elaborate a bit more? I can't really use xmlhttprequest object. Is there any other possible way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you can change the function of the button to call your web service.

And it will work just on your machine (where the web service is running)

^^